# Is there an easy way to bootstrap Arch Linux using chef?

Tags: arch-linux, chef

I'm aware that Arch Linux is not supported by chef.io, but is there anyway to bootstrap Arch Linux nodes using knife bootstrap?

I have tried the same command I use in Debian machines, but I get an error:

```sh
knife bootstrap 10.2.128.80 --ssh-identity-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa --connection-user myUser -N webserver --environment staging --bootstrap-version 18 -y --sudo
```

```sh
Connecting to 10.2.128.80 using ssh
Connecting to 10.2.128.80 using ssh

DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = cmd.exe /c ver
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Select Caption,Version | ConvertTo-Json
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = uname -s
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = uname -m
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = test -f /etc/debian_version
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = test -f /etc/os-release && cat /etc/os-release
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = show version
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = test -f /etc/lsb-release && cat /etc/lsb-release
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = test -f /etc/oracle-release && cat /etc/oracle-release
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = test -f /etc/enterprise-release && cat /etc/enterprise-release
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = test -f /etc/parallels-release && cat /etc/parallels-release
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = test -f /etc/system-release && cat /etc/system-release
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = test -f /etc/redhat-release && cat /etc/redhat-release
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = test -f /etc/SuSE-release && cat /etc/SuSE-release
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = test -f /etc/arch-release
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = uname -r
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = sh -c '(sudo echo) < /dev/null'
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = sudo echo '[SSH] Established'
WARNING: Performing legacy client registration with the validation key at /home/myUser/.chef/org-validator.pem...
WARNING: Remove the key file or remove the 'validation_key' configuration option from your config.rb (knife.rb) to use more secure user credentials for client registration.
TRACE: Looking for bootstrap template in /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.2.7/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/templates
TRACE: Found bootstrap template: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.2.7/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/templates/chef-full.erb
Bootstrapping 10.2.128.80
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = sudo sh /tmp/chef_T472LE/bootstrap.sh
 [10.2.128.80] -----> Installing Chef Omnibus (stable/18)
downloading https://omnitruck.chef.io/chef/install.sh
  to file /tmp/install.sh.32304/install.sh
 [10.2.128.80] trying wget...
 [10.2.128.80] "arch" "rolling" x86_64
 [10.2.128.80] Getting information for chef stable 18 for "arch"...
 [10.2.128.80] downloading https://omnitruck.chef.io/stable/chef/metadata?v=18&p="arch"&pv="rolling"&m=x86_64
  to file /tmp/install.sh.32308/metadata.txt
 [10.2.128.80] trying wget...
 [10.2.128.80] ERROR 404
 [10.2.128.80] Omnitruck artifact does not exist for version 18 on platform "arch"

Either this means:
   - We do not support "arch"
   - We do not have an artifact for 18

 [10.2.128.80] This is often the latter case due to running a prerelease or RC version of Chef
or a gem version which was only pushed to rubygems and not omnitruck.

You may be able to set your knife[:bootstrap_version] to the most recent stable
release of Chef to fix this problem (or the most recent stable major version number).

In order to test the version parameter, adventurous users may take the Metadata URL
 [10.2.128.80] below and modify the '&v=<number>' parameter until you successfully get a URL that
does not 404 (e.g. via curl or wget).  You should be able to use '&v=11' or '&v=12'
 [10.2.128.80] successfully.

 [10.2.128.80] If you cannot fix this problem by setting the bootstrap_version, it probably means
that "arch" is not supported.
 [10.2.128.80]
Metadata URL: https://omnitruck.chef.io/stable/chef/metadata?v=18&p="arch"&pv="rolling"&m=x86_64
 [10.2.128.80] Starting the first Chef Infra Client Client run...
 [10.2.128.80] /tmp/chef_T472LE/bootstrap.sh: line 364: chef-client: command not found
ERROR: The following error occurred on 10.2.128.80:
ERROR: -----> Installing Chef Omnibus (stable/18)
     downloading https://omnitruck.chef.io/chef/install.sh
       to file /tmp/install.sh.32304/install.sh
     trying wget...
     "arch" "rolling" x86_64
     Getting information for chef stable 18 for "arch"...
     downloading https://omnitruck.chef.io/stable/chef/metadata?v=18&p="arch"&pv="rolling"&m=x86_64
       to file /tmp/install.sh.32308/metadata.txt
     trying wget...
     ERROR 404
     Omnitruck artifact does not exist for version 18 on platform "arch"

     Either this means:
        - We do not support "arch"
        - We do not have an artifact for 18

     This is often the latter case due to running a prerelease or RC version of Chef
     or a gem version which was only pushed to rubygems and not omnitruck.

     You may be able to set your knife[:bootstrap_version] to the most recent stable
     release of Chef to fix this problem (or the most recent stable major version number).

     In order to test the version parameter, adventurous users may take the Metadata URL
     below and modify the '&v=<number>' parameter until you successfully get a URL that
     does not 404 (e.g. via curl or wget).  You should be able to use '&v=11' or '&v=12'
     successfully.

     If you cannot fix this problem by setting the bootstrap_version, it probably means
     that "arch" is not supported.

     Metadata URL: https://omnitruck.chef.io/stable/chef/metadata?v=18&p="arch"&pv="rolling"&m=x86_64
     Starting the first Chef Infra Client Client run...
      /tmp/chef_T472LE/bootstrap.sh: line 364: chef-client: command not found
DEBUG: [SSH] myUser@10.2.128.80 cmd = sudo rm -f "/tmp/chef_T472LE/bootstrap.sh"
```

I understand that since Arch Linux is not supported, it won't find the file to download at [the following URL](https://omnitruck.chef.io/stable/chef/metadata?v=18&p=%22arch%22&pv=%22rolling%22&m=x86_64).

Is there any way to trick it into thinking it is a supported OS? If it could download the file for a Debian install, would the rest of the installation still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

Basically, all you should have to do is install the package [`chef-client`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/chef-client) from AUR using the `knife bootstrap --bootstrap-install-command` flag

Personally, in my setup I don't have a user other than root, so I use [this script](https://repo.barata.pt/-/snippets/9/raw/master/bootstrap-arch.sh):

```sh
--bootstrap-install-command "curl -sSf https://repo.barata.pt/-/snippets/9/raw/master/bootstrap-arch.sh | sh"
```

I haven't tested, but something like this should work if you connect to the machine as a user with sudo without password configured:

```sh
pacman --noconfirm -S wget base-devel
cd /tmp
wget --no-verbose https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/chef-client.tar.gz
tar -xvf chef-client.tar.gz
cd chef-client
makepkg -si --noconfirm
cd ..
rm -rf chef-clien*
```

Full disclosure, the [`chef-client`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/chef-client) AUR package is currently being maintained by me